# Interchanging presentModalViewController and pushViewController

Tags: iphone, sdk, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I am using a sample ViewController that is displayed in the sample program as a presentModalViewController.   However, I want to use pushViewController on the UIViewController instead.  The problem is that when I switch to pushViewController, the ViewController no displays properly.   Functions in the ViewController are called, but I don't see anything.  I change back to presentModalViewController and everything works.

The question is what do I need to do to make pushViewController work?

```
FCVC *fcVC;  
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"fcVC" 
                                               owner:self     
                                             options:nil];  
fcVC = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

A. `[self presentModalViewController:fcVC animated:YES];`           // "WORKS"
or
B. `[self.navigationController pushViewController:fcVC animated:YES];`  // "Doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a UINavigationController actually set up? "self" should be a viewController that is loaded inside UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

To create a NavigationController in a view-based application you have to set the NavigationController in the delegate class.

Like This

```
In delegate .h class

  MyViewController *viewController;
```

In delegate .m class

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

UINavigationController *nvcontrol =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

[window addSubview:nvcontrol.view];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

Here "MyViewController" should be replaced by your viewcontroller.

All The Best.