# Switching Between View Controllers Efficiently

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

In order to switch between views in my iOS app, I have been using Modal View Controllers.  It works fine, but is this bad coding practice? Will it be detrimental to the memory usage of my app?

In response to comments asking for more information, the views I am switching between are normal informational views.  I am using three views to navigate through my app:

- Main View: Has buttons to navigate to specific informational views
- Info View: Has buttons to navigate to specific web pages for information
- Web View: Displays information through a UIWebview

I have an improvised navigation bar at the top for navigating "back" and "home" do the main page.

Overall, this is a web app with structure provided with menus in other views. I don't want to reveal what it does specifically (it's my idea), however this should be enough information to work with.

I am currently switching between views like this:

```
newViewController *newView = [[newViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:newView animated:YES];
```

Based on the answers so far, Modal Views are meant to quickly and temporarily display animations, but I am looking for a more permanent approach.

Is there a better way? Please provide example code with your response. Thank you!

EDIT: I apologize for originally not having enough information. I have posted a lot more information. If you need anything else, please comment.

Comment: This completely depends upon the overall structure of your app. Without more details, this question cannot be answered reasonably.

Comment: I apologize for originally not having enough information. I have posted a lot more information. If you need anything else, please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using modal view controllers is usually reserved for times when you need to display a view temporarily, as when the 'new message' controller is presented by Apple's Messages app. Another way to do what you want, which requires a little more setup, is:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
```

A nice explanation outlining the difference between the two can be found [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/12484209?messageID=12484209#12484209?messageID=12484209) as well as questions on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510072/diffrence-between-pushviewcontroller-and-presentmodalviewcontroller-in-iphone) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569928/interchanging-presentmodalviewcontroller-and-pushviewcontroller). A nice little tutorial on how to set up a `UINavigationController` can be found [here](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uinavigationcontroller-tutorial/), and a previous SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869787/uinavigationcontroller-custom-animation) covers the topic of custom animations, while some source code provided [here](http://mustafashaik.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/pushviewcontroller-with-custom-animation/) might also help you out. Phew. That's a lot of links.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by requiring more setup? Also, how would I choose a different animation than the default using this method?

Comment: Well by requiring more setup I mean just that you have to make sure that you must create a UINavigationController and use it to push and pop view controllers from the stack. It's really not too difficult. I'm revising my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Modal view controllers have a definite purpose of acquiring 'extra information' in a program flow. They are not designed to consume more/less memory. In fact no particular style of view controller is designed with memory consumption in mind. If you are gathering hierarchical bits of information, `UINavigationController` coupled with `UITableViewController` might be the way to go. Likewise, if you need a piece of information (and, say, you can't proceed without getting this information) you present a modal view controller (sort of) alerting the user.